# Session value changes on ajax page when using a random value

Tags: php, ajax, security, session, csrf

I am trying to prevent users from accessing my `POST/AJAX` files directly. I have decided to create a random token I call it "nonce_key". This key is created using a `SESSION` and then I pass it via `POST`. If the `SESSION` key is the same as the `POST` then I allow access. The problem is that sometimes it does not work.

Here is my workflow: 
I have a single select on my index.php that when the user changes its value it calls "change_status.php" via ajax.

For some reason the `SESSION` key set on index.php is not the same value as the `SESSION` key on change_status.php.

I have the following code in my functions.php file

```
function nonce_key()
{
    return hash('crc32b', time());
}
```

Then in my index I have

```
session_start();
require_once 'functions.php';

$_SESSION['nonce_key'] = nonce_key();

echo '
<script  type="text/javascript"> 
$"#change_status").bind("change",function() {
var form_data = {
nonce: "'.$_SESSION['nonce_key'].'",
id: $("#id").val(),
};

$.ajax({

type: "POST",
url: "change_status.php",
data: form_data,
success: function(result) {
  $("#message").slideDown("slow").html(result);
  }
 });
});
</script>'
;
```

Finally in my change_status.php file I have

```
session_start();
require_once 'functions.php';
if(isset($_SESSION['nonce_key']) && isset($_POST['nonce']))
{
   if($_SESSION['nonce_key'] == $_POST['nonce'])
   {
     change_app_status($_POST['id']);
   } else echo 'Nonce Invalid';
} else echo 'Not Allowed';
```

Comment: Looks right to me. Could there be anything else that might affect the session value? Why do you escape the \'change\' event in your jQuery? Since you (appreciated) only show your relevant code, might there be any other syntax that is wrong? Do the nonce_key get posted at all? How do they differ?

Comment: You have a strange mix of php and js in your `index`, can you check in the source code of the html that the javascript is as it is supposed to be?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Do you get 'Not Allowed' or do you get 'Nonce Invalid' or something else?

Comment: @OlafDietsche I get "Nonce Invalid" wile doing some debugging I saw that the $_SESSION['nonce_key'] is different on change_status.php than on index.php I don't understand why it changes on change_status.php since I only declare the value on index.php

Comment: @jtheman I changed my code to make more sense. But yes something must be changing the session value but I don't know what or how. I only give the value to the session at the beginning of the page.

Comment: @jeroen The javascript works fine it calls the ajax page.

Answer (score 0):

check that $_POST has the hash. And you have no need in `require_once 'functions.php';` in change_status.php. And you can make one if less by using ===

Comment: Yes the $_POST does have the hash. The problem is that the session value changes when it gets to change_status.php and I don't know how it changes since I only declare it at the beginning of index.php

Comment: This is not much of an answer, but rather a comment!